# Is it possible to select records based on order of in clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement in which I am using in clause.

Here is my table : MyTable

```
Id     SKU
1      112
2      223
3      445
4      456
5      678
```

If I write:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE SKU IN (112,223,445, 456, 678)
```

I an not getting result as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there any way to get select result based on items order in the in clause.?

Comment: "If I write: ... I am not getting result as ...", but you should if your "Here is my table : MyTable" statement is true. Your question obviously lacks of clarification of what you `really have` and what you `really want` as a result.

Comment: In short: no. If the values in the `IN` list are selected from another data source, e.g. a table or view, and you can obtain a suitable ranking therefrom, you could apply it separately, e.g. via a suitable `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score -1):

For your case `ORDER BY id` will be sufficient.

```
SELECT Id 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE SKU IN (112,223,445, 456, 678)
ORDER BY id
```

For general approach you could use `JOIN` with derived table like:

**[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/371256)**

```
SELECT m.Id 
FROM MyTable m
JOIN (VALUES (1, 112) ,(2,223) ,(3,445), (4,456), (5,678)) AS t(num, SKU)
  ON m.SKU = t.SKU 
ORDER BY t.num
```

If you use SQL Server 2008 you can use `UNION ALL`:

**[Demo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/371257)**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 112 AS SKU, 1 AS orderNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 223 AS SKU, 2 AS orderNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 445 AS SKU, 3 AS orderNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 456 AS SKU, 4 AS orderNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 678 AS SKU, 5 AS orderNum
)
SELECT m.Id 
FROM #MyTable m
JOIN cte c
  ON m.SKU = c.SKU 
ORDER BY c.orderNum;
```

General approach that does not force you to create custom query you could use temp table with `IDENTITY` column like:

**[Demo3](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/371258)**

```
CREATE TABLE #mySKU( orderNum INT IDENTITY(1,1), SKU INT);

INSERT INTO #mySKU
VALUES (112),(223),(445), (456), (678);

SELECT m.Id 
FROM #MyTable m
JOIN #mySKU c
  ON m.SKU = c.SKU 
ORDER BY c.orderNum;
```

Comment: what if the skus values are dynamic ? How can we use the general approach ?

Comment: @user123456 If SKUs are dynamic instead of IN ('a','b','c') you need to generate value pairs to JOIN like `((1, 'a'), (2, 'b',), (3, 'c'))`

Comment: **For downvoters I will be happy to know what is wrong with proposed solution**

Answer (score -1):

"Is there any way to get select result based on items order in the in clause?"

For this particular question the answer is **no**.